# React Router 4 showing 404 page on google cache

Tags: reactjs, seo, single-page-application, react-router-v4

When I try to see the cached version of my site on google cache 
it always renders 404 page

I think this is because react router does not understand the route because it is running on a different domain because of google cache.

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5Q4gZU5NIwJ:https://www.sitename.com/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution for this ?

Comment: @ShyamTayal Have you find the solution of this by yourself? can you assist me? I'm running into the same issue. Help appreciated. thanks.

Comment: @ShyamTayal , I have got a solution to this

Comment: @ShyamTayal I'm facing the same issue. Can you assit me?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, this appears to be at least one of the common issues folks have encountered: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5801

Comment: Links are useful but a complete answer should have more detail, otherwise if the link dies your answer is of little use. Cheers!